# How to fail the build from a Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm building a package manager, and I need to restore packages before each build.

I have hooked the DTE.OnBuildBegin to achieve this, which works fine, However if there is an error I need to fail the build.

I have discovered that I can add to the error list using the ErrorListProvider, which works great however the build still continues and succeeds. Even worse is that if you click run rather than build, the restore fails but the code still runs. And because Visual Studio uses a different view while running you don't see the error list while it is running.

[image]

How can I fail the build?

Comment: Maybe you could think about using the StopOnFirstBuildError extension tool: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EinarEgilsson.StopOnFirstBuildError

Comment: StopOnFirstBuildError  doesn't do what I want, it doesn't detect errors based on the error list, it does it based on the actual project builds, however StopOnFirstBuildError does cancel builds, so I took a look at there source code and that gave me the clue as to how to do it. (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will cancel the build.

```
DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
dte.ExecuteCommand("Build.Cancel");
```